# Rest Services and CAS validate

Tags: web-services, rest, forms-authentication, cas

I am trying to implement CAS validation on a Webserver that receives restful requests I only care if the ticket is valid then I can continue doing the operation. So web app `A` provides the client with content, the client will then do a post to restful webserver `B`. Webserver `B` will validate their ticket, and proceed.

I will only have access to the endpoints of the CAS server, no helper classes, dlls etc.

Here is the ticket provided, I'm positive it is correct. I pulled it from the web app that has the user logged in.

`ST-3285-1AijQkayTlcWSXQIVHUP-svvautht01.domain.org`

the service that was requested was `http://localhost:15559/WebApp/Main`

Here is the endpoint I am calling.

`https://svvautht01.domain.org:8443/cas/serviceValidate?ticket=ST-3285-1AijQkayTlcWSXQIVHUP-svvautht01.domain.org&service=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a15559%2fWebApp%2fMain`

I have tried the service with unencoded URL and both return the response below.

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationFailure code='INVALID_TICKET'>
        Ticket &#039;ST-3285-1AijQkayTlcWSXQIVHUP-svvautht01.domain.org&#039; not recognized
    </cas:authenticationFailure>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

I don't understand what I could be doing incorrectly. I can physically see that this is the correct ticket!

This is the Apereo jasig CAS found here [wiki jasig](https://wiki.jasig.org/)

Answer (score 1):

CAS Service Tickets by default have a [lifetime of 10 seconds](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.0.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#service-ticket) , after this time CAS itself will validate the user and any further validation requests for the same ST will show invalid ticket error